# Two person cabin on City Night Line train

Tags: trains, paris, berlin

My girlfriend and I are planing on taking one of the City Night Line trains from Paris to Berlin.

They have different cabins that can hold 2, 4 or 6 people. We want to get one that is just the two of us.

When I try and make a reservation online I see these options:

[image]

Anyone know which one is for just two people?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question relates to a train that no longer exists. This question is of historical interest only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one and the third one, i.e. the "Double" cabins are for two people.

The Deluxe cabins are a bit more luxurious and have their private WC and shower. The Economy cabins have only a washbasin. There you have to use a shared toilet. More information on the cabins can be found [here](http://www.citynightline.de/citynightline/view/en/service/komfortklassen/schlafwagen/comfortline_en.shtml).